# Why do only two cases in within my switch-statement work?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

when I run this code, it always falls through until "Quadrat". "Überraschung" also works perfectly. "Kreis" and "Dreieck" don't. And I really have no idea why that would be. Can you see why?

```
case 'Kreis':
    function draw() {
        ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);}
    break;  

case 'Dreieck':
    function draw() {
        triangle(30, 75, 58, 20, 86, 75);}
    break;

case 'Quadrat':
    function draw() {
        rect(30, 20, 55, 55);}
    break;

case 'Überraschung':
    var rN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (rN === 0) {
        function draw() {
            line(30, 20, 85, 75);}}
    else if (rN === 1) {
        function draw () {
            quad(38, 31, 86, 20, 69, 63, 30, 76);}}
    if (rN === 2) {
        function draw () {
            arc(50, 50, 80, 80, 0, PI + QUARTER_PI);}}
    break;

default:
    alert('Hast du was geschrieben, was ich verstehe?');
    break;}
```

Thank you for your time!

Comment: please add the switch part and the call of `draw` as well.

Comment: Don't declare functions in `switch`, use function arguments to pass the wanted action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change that into a single draw function, then switch inside it:

```
function draw() {
  switch (what) {
    case 'Kreis':
      ellipse(56, 46, 55, 55);
      break;
    case 'Dreieck':
      triangle(30, 75, 58, 20, 86, 75);
      break;
    case 'Quadrat':
      rect(30, 20, 55, 55);
      break;
    case 'Überraschung':
      var rN = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
      if (rN === 0) {
        line(30, 20, 85, 75);
      } else if (rN === 1) {
        quad(38, 31, 86, 20, 69, 63, 30, 76);
      }
      if (rN === 2) {
        arc(50, 50, 80, 80, 0, PI + QUARTER_PI);
      }
      break;
    default:
      alert('Hast du was geschrieben, was ich verstehe?');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This seems very easy and indeed it does work. The only thing though is... why does it work this way and not the other?

Comment: @Nat_ Like deceze said, defining a function multiple times is not just bad practice but might work differently in different environments. My way is unambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

`function` declarations are *hoisted*, conditional declaration of functions isn't a thing:

```js
if (true) {
    function foo() { console.log('foo'); }
} else {
    function foo() { console.log('bar'); }
}

foo();
```

The latter one <strike>always</strike> sometimes overwrites the former one,* the `if` isn't even evaluated before the functions are hoisted.

* Looks like different browsers behave differently here. Essentially it's undefined which declaration will be the canonical one.

If you want your symbol `draw` to dynamically assume different values, you cannot use function declarations but must use value assignment:

```
var draw;

switch (...) {
    ...
        draw = function () { ... };
}
```

Which here you can do like this for a bit of functional programming:

```
draw = ellipse.bind(null, 56, 46, 55, 55);
```

Comment: Shouldn't that snippet log `bar`?

Comment: It does for me. If it doesn't for you, that's even more proof that it's entirely unreliable to declare the same function twice.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick and helpful answer! I'm gonna try this later today!